# How to force permission check on overwritten post method of UpdateModelMixin?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm forced to write some messy work, I need to create partial_update view, however it must use POST method, because the software in the end does not use PUT/PATCH methods.

Here are some assumptions:

- everything needs to be routed via `DefaultRouter()` in `urls.py` - that's 
  why I'm using `GenericViewSet`
- must use POST method for updating one field - that's why I'm overwriting `post()` method of `UpdateModelMixin`
- `instance.visible` is a Boolean, which state is set to `True` as soon as the `body` is not empty.

Update works, except the `permission_classess` which are ignored. It totally does not check the request for valid credentials. I think it's because I totally overwrote the `post()`, right? How do I force authentication check within the post method?

**urls.py**:

```
from django.urls import include, path
from rest_framework import routers
from browse.views import *

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
[...]
router.register(r'update-article', UpdateArticleBodyViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('api/', include(router.urls)),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework'),)
]
```

**views.py**:

```
class UpdateArticleBodyViewSet(mixins.UpdateModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    queryset = Article.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ArticleSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated, )

    def post(self, request, pk):
        instance = get_object_or_404(Article, pk=pk)
        instance.body = request.data.get("body")
        if instance.body:
            instance.visible = True
        instance.save()
        serializer = self.get_serializer(instance=instance, data=request.data, partial=True)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

**UPDATE**

I've changed the code after the first question, now it looks like this:

**views.py**:

```
class UpdateArticleBodyViewSet(mixins.UpdateModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    queryset = Article.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ArticleSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated, )

    def partial_update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = self.queryset.get(pk=kwargs.get('pk'))
        instance.body = request.data.get("body")
        if instance.body:
            instance.visible = True
        instance.save()
        serializer = self.get_serializer(instance=instance, data=request.data, partial=True)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

**urls.py**

```
articles_viewset = UpdateArticleBodyViewSet.as_view({
    'post': 'update'
})

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'update-article', articles_viewset, basename="article")
```

Which results in following error:
`AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'get_extra_actions'`

There is a couple questions about it on StackOverflow already, but none of them provide the answer. Is there any way I can use Router in this case or am I forced to write urls explicitly?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that both classes you are inheriting from does not have a `post` method, so you are not actually overing it. So the method is out of the authentication scope.

There are a lot of different ways to accomplish this. The most simple way I can think of is to change the post action for your route. Something like:

```
articles_viewset = UpdateArticleBodyViewSet.as_view({
    'post': 'update'
})

router.register(r'update-article', articles_viewset)
```

This way, you would be able to use `UpdateMixin` without any problem. You sould just to tweak the `update` method if necessary.

Comment: Thank you, I knew I'm missing something obvious. Also good catch on no `post` method, I totally missed it. I have recoded the views part, however I'm struggling with urls.py. Your answer is missing the `basename` argument, which I have added (check the update of my question). However, I'm still stuck. Thanks in advance for looking into it.

Comment: Oh, I don't think it is possible to register a router with the `as_view` method. I would just lose the router, just create the url directly:

```urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^my_route/$', articles_viewset),
]```